# sort object of character occurance in descending order

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have used the JavaScript .forEach method to iterate through a given array of characters to return an object that indicates the character and the number of times the character occurs:

```
var textArray = [a, b, b, c, d, e, e, e, f];

var count = {};

textArray.forEach(function(elem) {
    count[elem] = count[elem] + 1 || 1;
});

console.log(count);
```

Would log:

```
{
a: 1,
b: 2,
c: 1,
d: 1,
e: 3,
f: 1
}
```

How can I then sort the object by descending occurrence? i.e.:

```
{
e: 3,
b: 2,
a: 1,
c: 1,
d: 1,
f: 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Redirected to previously answered question

Comment: See [this answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41048033/157247) and my comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this.

```js
function sort_object(list){
  var sorted_list= new Object();
  var sorted_keys=Object.keys(list)
                          .sort((b,a) => list[a]-list[b]);
  sorted_keys.forEach(function(val){
            sorted_list[val]=list[val];
  });
  
  return sorted_list;
}


var data = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 1, d: 1, e: 3};

console.log(sort_object(data));
```